# Вывод сохраненных значений при запуске приложения

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. У меня есть переменная int sitcoll = 25; , есть кнопка, по нажатии на которую в переменную sitcoll добавляет + 10 . и после выхода из приложения сохраняеться значение sitcoll, но после входа в приложение сохраненные данные обнавляються только после нажатия на кнопку которая добавляет + 10 в sitcoll.
**Буду благодарен за помошь. я хочу сделать чтоб войдя в приложение, срузу выводилось обновленное значение**

- Код GameView.java:

  ```
  public class GameView extends Activity {

  public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";
  public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_COUNTER = "counter";
  private SharedPreferences mSettings;

  TextView SitostCat;
  int sitcoll = 25;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
  /* Скрываем строку состояния */
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  setContentView(R.layout.gameview);
  mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


  SitostCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sitost);
  SitostCat.setText("Сытость " + sitcoll);


  }

  public void plus(View view) {
      switch (view.getId()) {
      case R.id.button1:

          SitostCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sitost);
          SitostCat.setText("Сытость " + sitcoll);

  sitcoll = sitcoll + 10;
          break;
      }
  }


  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      // Запоминаем данные
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
      editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_COUNTER, sitcoll);
     editor.apply();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();

      if (mSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_COUNTER)) {
          // Получаем число из настроек
         sitcoll = mSettings.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_COUNTER, 0);
          // Выводим на экран данные из настроек

      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: Поаккуратней с тегами, пожалуйста. В прошлом вопросе был только один тег `int`, в этом тоже что-то невнятное... Оба случая - это `java, android`. А ваш тег `обновление` вообще ни к селу, ни к городу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По умолчанию переменная `sitcoll` имеет значение `25`, значение в `TextView` вы устанавливаете в методе `onCreate`, соответственно при каждом запуске у вас будет выводиться значение `25`. [В жизненом цикле приложения](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) метод `onResume` вызывается после метода `onCreate` , поэтому значение из настроек у вас считывается уже после того как вы установили значение в поле. Вам необходимо в методе `onCreate` сначала получить значение из настроек, а потом устанавливать его в `TextView`. И еще, в методе plus не обязательно повторно искать `TextView`, т.к. вы его уже нашли и сохранили в методе `onCreate`.

```
onCreate(){

    if (mSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_COUNTER)) {
        // Получаем число из настроек
       sitcoll = mSettings.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_COUNTER, 0);
        // Выводим на экран данные из настроек

    }

    SitostCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sitost);
    SitostCat.setText("Сытость " + sitcoll);
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь. еще один момент, вы написали что "в методе plus не обязательно повторно искать TextView", но если его не искать в этом методе, то после нажатия кнопки значение переменной sitcoll не обновляется . этому есть какое-нибудь решение? или же лучше искать sitcoll в методе plus?

Comment: Искать не обязательно, но вызывать метод setText обязательно. И судя по вашему коду Вы сначала устанавливаете значение в поле, а потом только прибавляете 10